# SMC Fan Control Causing random freezing and crashing

Tags: macos, high-sierra, power-management, cooling

After experiencing crashing and freezing on [15" MacBook Pro 2017](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP756?locale=en_US) (macOS High Sierra), I started eliminating running programs that I thought might be causing the crashing as advised by an apple support employee.

I immediately suspected that it might be smc fan control (A program that hasn't been updated since [2016](https://www.eidac.de/))

After removing the program I noticed that the problems stopped.

However it is useful to pre-emptively turn fan speed up before using a resource intensive program. My lap has also threatened to leave me if I don't resolve this issue.

Has anyone else experienced this or am I alone? Are there other alternatives for fan control in osx.

Comment: You write: "My lap has also threatened to leave me if I don't resolve this issue." I suggest you see a physician.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short list of apps that you can try.  I've listed them by price (lowest to highest).  All of them specifically state that they support High Sierra.

- [SSD Fan Control](http://exirion.net/ssdfanctrl/) (Free)
- [Macs Fan Control](https://www.crystalidea.com/macs-fan-control) ($15)
- [TGPro](https://www.tunabellysoftware.com/tgpro/) ($18)
- [HDD Fan Control](http://www.hddfancontrol.com/) ($35)

Comment: I tried Macs Fan Control (tended to make fan speed up and slow down rapidly.  Then tried and bought TG Pro, which works well so far and has a flexible way to define rules to boost fan speed based on temperature.